# 'Ng2SmartTableModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table, ngx-admin

...
Create a new project after using yarn add ng2-smart-table
Have an error in imports
(alias) class Ng2SmartTableModule
import Ng2SmartTableModule
'Ng2SmartTableModule' does not appear to be a NgModule class. (-996002)
ng2-smart-table.module.d.ts(1, 22): This likely means that the library (ng2-smart-table) declares Ng2SmartTableModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer library version is available, and update if so. Also, consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

...

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Ng2SmartTableModule } from 'ng2-smart-table'; // add
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    Ng2SmartTableModule, // add
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Please share `package.json`.

Comment: `"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.7.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },`

Answer (score 0):

Poor documentation on the package. From what I tested this lib seems compatible up to Angular 9 - which makes sense seeing that last update to package was 2 years ago and Angular releases new major version twice a year.

Angular 9 still working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-starter-material-21jfey?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Better look for alternatives

http://primefaces.org/primeng/table

https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/overview